# SSLHandshakeException Error in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, ssl-certificate, performance-testing, sslhandshakeexception

I am encountering this error while recording the Jmeter scripts.

I already have JDK 1.7 installed in my machine however it did not help. I am getting the following error message:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source) at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.sample(HTTPJavaImpl.java:487) at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74) at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105) at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094) at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429) at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Did you try to disable SNI? -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false

Answer (score 0):

As per [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](http://blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) guide clearing your browser's history should help.

Comment: I am getting the same error but clearing browser's history didn't help.